# OSS Software for Quran Corpus(text annotations)

Tags: text-processing, opensource-projects

Is there any software that can produce annotations like this:

[image: corpus-layout]

Link: https://corpus.quran.com/treebank.jsp?chapter=112&verse=1

I found a few options here: https://corpus-analysis.com/tag/annotation

Most of the open source options(and commercial ones) do some of the things and the closest is: https://inception-project.github.io/

but ... none of these tools can do exactly what is shown on the Quran Corpus.

The Quran Corpus web software itself is not Open Sourced anywhere, even though its website says it is.

I asked about doing this in Latex: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622632/building-quran-corpus

But this is painstakingly manual. So if some software exists that can handle the syntactic relations, then it is just the translations/transliterations needed.

Comment: The Java API that they provide is [available for download](https://corpus.quran.com/java/download.jsp) from the site that you linked to.  An overview of the API is [also available](https://corpus.quran.com/java/overview.jsp) on that site, it seems.  The rest is a programming exercise in Java.

Comment: it is assumed I know how to program and how to program in Java too. If I don't, then what would the answer be?